# Синонимы слова "крышка"

Tags: лексика, синонимы

Необходимо в тексте сократить число **крышек**.
Крышка люка, крышка сундука и крышка ларца присутствуют в одной главе, в одном и том же месте. Они то открываются, то закрываются, и от этого получаются целые абзацы, забитые крышками!
Мой мозг синонимов не нашёл. Перелопатил текст, как мог, иносказаниями и прочими "словесы", но всё равно "крышки" торчат! Интернет же не знает ничего, кроме "амба" и "хана котёнку".
Может быть кому-нибудь придёт в голову светлая идея?

Comment: А почему просто не закрывать некоторые объекты типа сундука, конструкция которых всегда имеет крышку?

Comment: Точно, тогда количество крышек значительно сократится.

Comment: Не совсем понял, что значит"закрывать"? У меня крышку сундука надо нащупывать, придерживать, открывать, закрывать, касаться, проверять и т.д.. Она ещё и хлопает и несёт в себе угрозу. И каждый раз это крышка, крышка, крышка... Можно пару раз на 15 страниц текста вставить иносказание, но ими тоже не стоит злоупотреблять.

Answer (score 2):

Кое-что нашлось. Возможно, что-то Вам подойдет.
,
[**Бленда**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0) — крышка для объектива, фотоаппарата.
[**Лючина**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/183029/%D0%9B%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0) — крышка люка.
[**Рустер**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/155657/%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80) — покрышка, решетка.
Капот — откидная покрышка у различных механизмов, предохраняющая их от пыли, сырости и т. п.

[**О сундуках**](http://womanwiki.ru/w/%D0%A1%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BA):
Позднее сундуку добавили четыре ножки, поставив его на них. Крышку заменили двумя дверками. Внутри сделали полочки и выдвижные ящики. Так из сундука родился современный шкаф.

Т. о. получается, что у сундука могут быть и крышка, и дверка, и дверца, и створка.

*Михаил закрепил факел на стене и попробовал открыть сундук, но ничего не получилось. Поискал ключ. Ключа нигде не было. Тогда Михаил применил свой метод открывания. Ломиком взломал замок и осторожно открыл **дверцу сундука...***
И. Северенчук

*Но горбатый **верх сундука** с продольными ребрами, обитый латунными накладками, обшарпанный верх с заклепками, которые прощупывались под...

Мы раскрывали его желтые целлулоидные **створки** с кнопками на кожаных застежках и вытряхивали содержимое на пол...*
А. Житинский

*Перехватив у нее ручку, он медленно **откинул верх сундука.***
Е. Сухов

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ
Кстати, у люков не обязательно должны быть крышки. Могут присутствовать — в зависимости от предназначения и конструкции — ещё и заглушки, и створы.

*Когда **заглушка люка** открылась, из отверстия вырвалось облако пара – такого горячего, что Нат невольно отпрянул, чтобы не ошпариться.*
С. Брюссоло

*Глядя на то, как массивные **створы люка** смыкаются у меня над головой, я приуныл.*
Р. Глушков

Comment: Спасибо! Честно говоря, не могу представить, как крышку сундука можно назвать "дверцей". Это же абсолютно разные вещи! Это тоже самое, что крышу дома назвать дверью! Вот "лючина" - это хорошо! Можно вставить куда-нибудь. Действие происходит в приблизительном аналоге конца XVI - начала XVII века, так что выбор у меня не велик.

Comment: Кстати! Это смешно, но со словом "сундук" проблемы те же! Очень мало синонимов.

Comment: Посмотрите на особый сундук-подголовник, вот здесь https://www.petli-zamki.ru/news/5133/ и вот здесь https://www.google.ru/search?q=%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA&newwindow=1&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjBy8zq8IfaAhVDaFAKHb2gDPYQsAQIJQ&biw=1366&bih=651. Я, конечно, не специалист по мебели, но все-таки думаю, что там не крышка, а дверка или створка.

Comment: По первой ссылке - очень похож. Фото моё - https://pp.userapi.com/c309225/v309225864/10e7/VdktxeQMHvo.jpg По второй ссылке - больше похоже на дорожный сундук. Здесь такое не прокатит. А можно, я выложу временно главу и здесь размещу ссылку? Потом удалю. Простят модераторы такое? А вас попрошу прочитать текст и меня потом наругать за все эти повторы? А?

Answer (score 1):

Несколько вариантов, их допустимость зависит от контекста использования: поверхность, верх, верхушка, навершие, покрытие, перекрытие, дверца, дверка, клапан, закрывашка, горизонталь.

Несколько метафорические: купол, макушка, холм, "лобное место", площадь, площадка, плато.

Удачи!

Comment: Спасибо! С удовольствием бы применил что-нибудь подобное, если бы была возможность. Но только крышку люка можно назвать "люком" в общем смысле. А вот для крышки сундука не подойдут ни "макушка", ни "дверка", ни "верхушка". В любом контексте. "Открыть верх сундука" или "откинуть верх сундука" как-то не по-русски.

Answer (score 1):

Надо выделить крышку люка, потому что она круглая, и использовать метафору, например: **чугунная тарелка люка**.

И вообще, по возможности **замаскировать** крышки определениями.

Comment: С люком проблем меньше. Его крышка - это простой деревянный щит, какой до сих пор используют в деревнях, для лаза в подпол. Можно обыграть и как щит, и (как мне подсказали - лючину). А вот с сундуком проблем больше, а вариантов меньше - для плоской крышки старинного сундука я подобрал только одно замещение - "короб". "Верх" - это хорошо, но как-то не ложится в текст.

Comment: И здесь, под этим дощатым коробом, обитым железной полосой, его наверняка дожидался ценный приз!

Answer (score 1):

*Кожух* — покрышка разных форм, верх футляра; *пробка* в т. ч. для горла банки, термоса; *шляпка* — пробка с полями, *колпачок* — крышечка с обнимающими полями, крышка-кисточка, крышка-пипетка.